# Can't make random image show javascript

Tags: javascript

Attempting to show a random image in a set based on an average.  I believe my code is working:

```
var happy = ["/images/rick.gif", "/images/troll.gif", "/images/wild.gif","/images/pervkid.gif"],
   rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * happy.length);

  console.log(avg);  

    if (avg > 2) {
        document.getElementById("bod").innerHTML = happy[rand];
    }
```

Because the random images selected will show, in name only, text, at random on refresh, but I cannot get the images to show.  Have also tried ".src" which just gives me a blank screen.

Comment: It needs an image tag too ... `'<img src="' + happy[rand] + '" alt="">'`

Comment: Can you create a snippet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need e.g. an `img` tag too

```
document.getElementById("bod").innerHTML = '<img src="' + happy[rand] + '" alt="">';
```

Comment: Thats it. Thank you.

Comment: Will "Accept" when they allow me in 10 mins.